# How to change image based on number of taps in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK and currently I have this. When you tap on the image the number increases. I was wonder how would I change the image once it reached a certain amount of clicks?

```
   display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

   local newButton = display.newImage ("button.png",0,0)
   newButton.x = display.contentWidth - 60
   newButton.y = display.contentHeight - 62.5

   local number = 0
   local textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)

   local function moveButtonRandom(event)
       number = number + 1
       textField:removeSelf()
       textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)
   end


   newButton:addEventListener("tap", moveButtonRandom)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use a sprite and when you increment to a certain point, tell the sprite to play the next frame.

There are multiple tutorial on working with imageSheets and sprites here: http://coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/images-audio-video-animation/

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can make an if then decision statement in your function and use number as argument. When statement true switch the pictures.

Example: if number >= 3 then 
--[[after 3 clicks Remove existing picture and add new picture code executes here--]]
End

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want an image to show up when you get to 15 clicks, you can modify your tap function to look like this, so that the number gets replaced by an image:

```
local function moveButtonRandom(event)
   number = number + 1

   -- Here goes our if check

   if number >= 15 then
       -- The number of clicks is 15 or more, replace the numbers with an image
       textField:removeSelf()
       textField = display.newImage("yourImage.png")
   else
       -- Do things the 'normal' way
       textField:removeSelf()
       textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)
   end
end
```

If you dont want the image to replace the text, then create a new local variable at the top of your file, and assign it inside the if check